# error: Placeholder matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-cms

i'm working on a project using Django CMS. Right now im getting the following error while trying to visit my page:

```
 Exception Type: DoesNotExist
 Exception Value: Placeholder matching query does not exist.
```

It gives the error at the following line:

```
<div class="practical-info">{% show_placeholder "practical-info" "snippets" %}</div>
```

Im not quite sure what to do next. I've used a sqldumb to get all the data in the database, used

```
manage.py syncdb
```

and

```
manage.py migrate
```

to set everything up, and did it without any errors.

Hopefully someone could give me some insight in this problem! Since i don't even know what causes it exactly, it's hard for me to find a solution to it!

thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting this error because the cms is expecting a page with the name "snippets" that contains a placeholder called "practical-info".  This is likely something that you'll have to create in the admin (or load via a fixture).

If this was a working site before, likely there is a cms template with the "practical-info" placeholder on it.  Create a new Page using the cms template containing that placeholder and then, under the "Advanced Settings" formset on the Page detail admin, set "snippets" to the value of id.